# Weird problem trying to write typesafe ISA functions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the compiler enforce that my ISA functions actually work, using refinement and (at the end) assigning the input to a typed const:

```
export interface Foo {
    tag: string;
}

function isaFoo(x:unknown): x is Foo {
    if (typeof x !== "object" || !x) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!("tag" in x) || typeof x.tag !== "string") { return false; }

    const str:string = x.tag; // Fine, TSC knows x.tag is string.
    // const num:number = x.tag; // Expected error, "string is not assignable to number"

    const typesafeFoo:Foo = x; // Err: tag is incompatible, unknown is not string

    return true;
}
```

...but I'm having a problem: As I refine x, typescript discards the type of properties, adding `Record<"tag", unknown>` instead of `Record<"tag", string>`, which causes the final assignment to fail.

Is this a bug, or is there an explicit reason the information is being "forgotten" when applied to the type of `x` even though it applies to `x.tag`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why this is failing, however a workaround is to create a second type assertion, and it all seems to work:

```js
export interface Foo {
    tag: string;
}

function isaFoo(x:unknown): x is Foo {
    if (typeof x !== "object" || !x) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!("tag" in x)) { return false; }
    if (!isString(x)) { return false }

    const str:string = x.tag; // Fine, TSC knows x.tag is string.
    // const num:number = x.tag; // Expected error, "string is not assignable to number"

    const typesafeFoo:Foo = x; // Err: tag is incompatible, unknown is not string

    return true;
}

function isString(x: Record<'tag', unknown>): x is Record<'tag', string> {
    return typeof x.tag === 'string'
}
```

Comment: Yes, calling out to another function that makes assertions about x as a whole works, which is what I'm going with for now, but I was hoping to be able to inline it without having a bunch of `hasProp(x,"name",isaFoo)` calls.

Comment: Yep agreed - I am also interested to learn why this isn't working as expected.